# jQuery on-screen clock memory leak

Tags: jquery

I have the following which is updating an  element on the screen, and I can't seem to prevent it from consuming memory, it is consuming roughly 0.10% or ram every minute.

I have already tried to null all of the variables, but nothing I seem to do will stop this leak.

```
function TimeTick(){
    var lt = new Date(); 
    lt.setMilliseconds(lt.getMilliseconds()-g_svros);
    var ch=lt.getHours(), cm=lt.getMinutes(), cs=lt.getSeconds(); 
    if(ch==0) ch=12; 
    $('#clock').val((ch >12?ch-12:ch)+":"+(cm<10?"0":"")+cm+":"+(cs<10?"0":"")+cs+" "+(ch>=12?"PM":"AM"));
    lt=null;ch=null;cm=null;cs=null;
}
var tick = setInterval('TimeTick()',250);
```

I profiled the memory usage of the browser from the command prompt by sampling the browser process.

If I disable this function, then the memory does not increas and stays perfectly stable !

Comment: how did you memory profiled it

Comment: You're creating a new object every tick. If all you're trying to do is update the time, you only need one date object...

Comment: Does increasing the interval make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

`'TimeTick()'` is being eval`d every 250ms.

See if this makes a difference:

```
var tick = setInterval(function () {
    TimeTick();
}, 250);
```

See eval benchmarks [here](http://moduscreate.com/javascript-performance-tips-tricks/).

Comment: The question was about memory usage, not speed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle that removes the eval and function declaration, and moves the jquery selector outside the function: http://jsfiddle.net/aBvdy/1/

```
$(function() {
    var g_svros = 0;
    var clock = $('#clock');
    var tick = setInterval(function() {
        var lt = new Date(); 
        lt.setMilliseconds(lt.getMilliseconds()-g_svros);
        var ch=lt.getHours(), cm=lt.getMinutes(), cs=lt.getSeconds(); 
        if(ch==0) ch=12; 
        clock.val((ch >12?ch-12:ch)+":"+(cm<10?"0":"")+cm+":"+(cs<10?"0":"")+cs+" "+(ch>=12?"PM":"AM"));
    }, 250);
});
```

I watched the Chrome process manager for about 5 minutes, only very slight fluctuations in memory usage for that tab. Nothing to call home about.

Comment: deleted due to longer test

Comment: OK, have been testing this solution, an improvement over my original, now the memory is climbing at about 0.1% every 6 minutes, rather than every minute or so, but I would still like to get this to zero, as after many hours or days, eventually all of the memory will be used.

Comment: That is an issue with the browser and the OS. You can open `about:blank` and the same thing will happen. Browsers use memory in pages at a time, and the OS cleans it up every once in a while. It'll climb and it'll garbage-collect. You are trying to accomplish something beyond your control. Be happy with the 0.1%/6minute memory usage.

Comment: Thanks Joe, but if I disable this function, the memory usage does not appear to grow at all. The O/S is Arch Linux, the browser is Midori (webkit)

Answer (score 0):

Let's do some optimizations (when I say each time I mean each iteration of the TimeTick function):

1. <s>Stop creating new date object each time since it is fairly [costly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/951021/1266600) (it's useful if you want to block up the browser!)</s> Nevermind, you need to do this to get the new Date each time.
2. Don't reselect `#clock` element each time, jQuery has to access the DOM each time
3. Use anonymous function instead of eval since eval entails much more [overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/86580/1266600) (parsing, etc.)
4. Remove the nulling of variables, what did these achieve? Since JS has function scope, `ch`, `cs`, and `cs` are destroyed at the end of each `TimeTock` and then garbage collected.

Modified Code:

```
function TimeTick(lt, clock) {
     lt.setMilliseconds(lt.getMilliseconds()-g_svros);
     var ch= lt.getHours(), cm=lt.getMinutes(), cs=lt.getSeconds(); 
     if(ch==0) ch=12; 
     clock.val((ch >12?ch-12:ch)+":"+(cm<10?"0":"")+cm+":"+(cs<10?"0":"")+cs+" "+(ch>=12?"PM":"AM"));
}

var clock = $('#clock'); //Optimization 2
var tick = setInterval(function() {
    TimeTick(new Date(), clock); //Optimization 3
}, 250);
```

Comment: You need to create a new Date each time. This does not update the time otherwise.

Comment: @JoeFrambach, ah very true. I did not realize this. Edited.